# No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, method-missing, missingmethodexception

Currently I've got a runtime exception: 'Systen.MissingMethodException : No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

I've googled and came across a lot of people actually not having a default contstructor, though my code actually does, so I don't know where it goes wrong!

My full code can be found here on pastebin since its varely large: http://pastebin.com/RxdKgxSx

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does your controller have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Yes:        public CursusController()
        {
            _agent = new BSCursusBeheerAgent();
        }

        public CursusController(ICursusBeheer agent)
        {
            _agent = agent;
        }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace:

```
public ActionResult Create(UploadViewItem viewItem, HttpPostedFile postedFile)
```

with:

```
public ActionResult Create(UploadViewItem viewItem, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
```

ASP.NET MVC works with abstractions over the actual `HttpContext` objects (`HttpContextBase`, `HttpRequestBase`, `HttpResponseBase`, `HttpSessionBase`, `HttpPostedFileBase`, ...).

That's what allows for easier unit testing and mocking those objects.

For more information about uploading files in ASP.NET MVC you may checkout the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx).

Comment: Glad I could help. Any other questions or you might consider accepting this answer?

Comment: Thank you bro it helped me too